# Unable to iterate through JSON data

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to loop through JSON data to find values for specific keys.  My data is coming from a http request and the data looks like:

```
{'1': {'manufacturername': 'SVLJ',
       'modelid': 'TCL014',
       'name': 'Fling'},
'10': {'manufacturername': 'SONY',
    'modelid': 'BLL4554',
    'name': 'ACQ'}}
```

My current goal is to loop through each item number (1, 10, etc..) and get the value for light ('fling', 'acq', etc..).  My latest attempt is:

```
import requests

RESOURCE_URL = 'xxx/xxx/'

def get_json(url):
    raw_response = requests.get(url)
    data = raw_response.json()
    return data

def get_SMR():
    url = "{}SMR/".format(RESOURCE_URL)
    return get_json(url)

smr_json = get_SMR()

for SMR in smr_json:
    print(SMR['name'])
```

When I try running this, I get the error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I've also tried importing the json library, and using json.loads(raw_response.text); however, it's still being recognized as a string, rather than an iterable json object (that can be referenced by key).  Any and all insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing `for SMR in smr_json:`, you are *iterating over the keys of the dictionary*. In other words, `SMR` is a string, which does not allow indexing by a string:

```
In [1]: SMR = 'test'

In [2]: SMR['string']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
...  
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

You've meant to iterate over both the keys and values:

```
for key, SMR in smr_json.items():
    print(SMR['name'])
```

Or, just values:

```
for SMR in smr_json.values():
    print(SMR['name'])
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much for clearing that up for me.  I appreciate the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting a string because that is not valid JSON. JSON requires `"` for strings, not `'`.

See [json.org](https://www.json.org/):

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in JSON file. Single quotes are not allowed.

I'd first replace the single quotes ' with the double quotes " , to have something like this:

```html
{
 "1": {
  "manufacturername": "SVLJ",
  "modelid": "TCL014",
  "name": "Fling"
 },
 "10": {
  "manufacturername": "SONY",
  "modelid": "BLL4554",
  "name": "ACQ"
 }
}
```